# Stop request group on failure

Tags: paw-app

Apologies if I'm just missing something in the UI, but is there a way to stop processing requests in a request group once one of the requests fails (returns anything other than 20x)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not yet possible. We'd love to be able to add such a feature in a next release of Paw! Thanks for suggesting!